# Only first row from sql query is displaying

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

My trying to show product desc in pop up. Mean when i click on product link then one pop up will open and show product desc. but here something is wrong. every product link showing first  product desc. My code is Below. Please help me out.

**Javascript:**

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function displayPopup(alert_MSG) 
    {
       var theDetail = document.getElementById('flyBox');
            theDetail.style.display="block";
    }

    function closePopup(alert_MSG)
    {

        var theDetail = document.getElementById('flyBox');

        if (theDetail.style.display=="block") 
        {
            theDetail.style.display="none";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
                        <a href="javascript:displayPopup('flyBox')" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
                      <div id="flyBox" style="display:none;">
                      <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>

                    <td align="center">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="borderWindow">
                    <div class="container">
                    <div id="closeButton"><a href="javascript:closePopup('flyBox')"><img src="http://i1122.photobucket.com/albums/l523/Long_Islander/flyBoxClose.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Close Button" border="0" /></a></div>
                    <div class="content">
                    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div id="myMessageBox" name="myMessageBox">
                    <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="colheadingL"><font color="white">Description</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                            <td ><?php echo $img; ?></td>
                            <td>Book Name:</td>
                            <td ><?php echo $row['pname']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text1">MRP:</td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['price'];?> </td>


                    </tr>



                </table>
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
```

But pop up is open click on hyperlink. but problem is showing only 1'st record in all product

Comment: well, your code has no intention to show an array of records. If it had, then there should be at least a loop iterating over the records :-)

Comment: Your JavaScript displays a div with the id flybox for which there is only the description of one item inside.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have loop any in your template script, that is why you see just one record vizualized.

I don't know exactly how your code is organized outside of the snippet you have posted, but assuming your data rows are in `$rows` array variable, the code will look something like that:

```
<? foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
<tr>
  <td ><?php echo $img; ?></td>
  <td>Book Name:</td>
  <td ><?php echo $row['pname']; ?></td>
  <td class="text1">MRP:</td>
  <td><?php echo $row['price'];?> </td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: @deepeshsharma But you should not run **all** code in while loop, but just the part I  have specified. If you run all template code in while loop you will recieve a lot of popup boxes with one product in every one.

Comment: @deepeshsharma So use code I posted but change `$rows` on `$query`. Delete your current loop, and add two additional lines `<? foreach($query as $row) { ?>` and `<? } ?>` as I wrote above.

Comment: Buddy i wrote that code now. But now every product showing all product desc. But i want corresponding product desc....

Answer (score 0):

Try to make IDs of each DIV as Unique.

Below is the sample code, try to use it as per your requirement

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function displayPopup(id) 
{
   var theDetail = document.getElementById(id);
        theDetail.style.display="block";
}

function closePopup(id)
{

    var theDetail = document.getElementById(id);

    if (theDetail.style.display=="block") 
    {
        theDetail.style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>


<?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){?>
<div>
             <a href="javascript:displayPopup('flyBox_<?php echo $i;?>')" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
             <div id="flyBox_<?php echo $i;?>" style="display:none;">
                 <div id="closeButton"><a href="javascript:closePopup('flyBox_<?php echo $i;?>')"><img src="http://i1122.photobucket.com/albums/l523/Long_Islander/flyBoxClose.png" width="28" height="28" alt="Close Button" border="0" /></a></div>
                  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo "Div ".$i. " Content comes here";?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div> 
</div>
<?php }?>
```