# my modal in image responsive show only first row image from database

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

I tried to make responsive image for all image thumbnail from my database. 
the thumbnail is showing, but when I clicked it, all of it display the first image only. why this is happening?

here is a few line code from **view file**

```html
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <table id="dynamic-table" method="post" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Nama Lengkap</th>
        <th>Tanggal Mulai</th>
        <th>Tanggal Akhir</th>
        <th>Alasan</th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Nopeg</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($hasil->result() as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row->no ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row->nama ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row->tglm ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row->tgla ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row->alasan ?></td>

        <td>

          <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->file ?>" height="75">

          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->file ?>" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row->nopeg; ?></td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm">Terima</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Tolak</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
        $(".img-responsive").attr("src", image);
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

here is a code from **model**

```js
<? php

class Model_data_cuti extends CI_Model {

  public

  function getdata() {
    $hasil = $this - > db - > query("SELECT * FROM form");
    return $hasil;

  }
  public

  function create($data_form) {
    $this - > db - > insert('form', $data_form);
  }
  public

  function find($no) {
    $hasil = $this - > db - > where('no', $no) - > limit(1) - > get('form');
    if ($hasil - > num_rows() > 0) {
      return $hasil - > row();
    } else {
      return array();
    }
  }
} ?>
```

and this is from **controller**

```js
<? php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Data_cuti extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this - > load - > model('model_data_cuti');
  }
  public
  function index() {

    $data['hasil'] = $this - > model_data_cuti - > getdata();
    $this - > load - > view('data_cuti_view', $data);

  }
} ?>
```

this is the result page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYION.png)

look at the file column. if i clicke th image, it only display image from first row. when i click others image, it display the first image too.

Comment: Is the JS part correct? Shouldn't `e.relatedTarget` raise an error?

Comment: I don't know. I just paste it from somewhere wish something happen. but no error raised

Comment: hmm wait i deleted this line in snippet "$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) ". @MargaretBloom.

Comment: Oh, that makes *much* more sense now. Edit the question (there is an *edit* button just below the tag line, on the bottom left) to add the missing code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom done editing. I think I have something to do with the $row->file image responsive Modal. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923614/only-first-row-from-sql-query-is-displaying . but i don't know what to do. I'm new in codeigniter and bootstrap

Comment: @MarisaSilvana, maksudnya modal pop upnya gak sesuai sama yg di klik ya?

Comment: @codeK.O. iyaa..pas diklik gambar ke dua, gambar yg muncul tetep gambar pertama dan seterusnya. mohon bantuannya T.T

Comment: yang ngajarin pake related target siapa?

Comment: tuh dah ku jawab, kl bener di accept ya.. 
btw aku jg orang jakarta loh.. A_A

Comment: @codeK.O. ga tau... saking hopeless nya.. ga ada jawaban. haha. tapi masih ngga bisa.. udah diganti sama punya situ. yaa tetep di dalem loop si <td> <img> dll nya.

Comment: @Michan, javascript gak bisa baca redundan `id`, kl ada double js-nya gak works..

Answer (score 0):

> I see there in your **view** code, you tried to get the image by
>   `e.relatedTarget` for modify your modal.

---

**Mistake :**

You do loop the modals, but declare the same `id`, it was write such as :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

If you inspect the element in your browser you will find that you have a lot of modals with  the same `id`.

---

**Approach Solution :**

Just move out the modals from the loop condition, and try to modify it by `onclick` event listener inside of the true image of yours.

---

**Code Provided ( Untested ) :**

```
<td> <img onclick="photoModal('<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->file ?>');" src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->file ?>" height="75">

<script>
  function photoModal(imgPath){
        $('#myModal < div < div < div <img').attr("src",imgPath);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
</script>
```

---

**Explanation**
So, while you clicked the image, it will trigger `function photoModal()` to send the `src` attribute to the Modal and proccess it to change the `src` image inside of Modals

Comment: so do you mean I should remove the modals? I tried it, just like yours. But it become not responsive.

Comment: i mean move out it from the loops.. :D
keluarin dari kondisi loop.

Comment: i have no idea where to move the modal >.<, please check http://pastebin.com/E2vXeN0v

Comment: i doubt my js delegate.. i must try to your actually code..
Do you host your program to online?

Comment: hmm.. not yet.. do you want to try it? maybe I can send it through email

Answer (score 0):

I already trick it with some code. My purpose is to make the image larger, so the user can read it.
ps: I already removed the modals.

here is my code in **view**

```html
<table id="dynamic-table" method="post" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Nama Lengkap</th>
      <th>Tanggal Mulai</th>
      <th>Tanggal Akhir</th>
      <th>Alasan</th>
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Nopeg</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($hasil->result() as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->no ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->nama ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->tglm ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->tgla ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row->alasan ?></td>

      <td>
        <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->file ?>"> 
 <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row->file ?>" width="50" height="50">
 </a>

      </td>

      <td>
        <?php echo $row->nopeg; ?></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm">Terima</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Tolak</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if you have another way to make the modal working right, just tell me. thanks. ^^,